# ExpandableListItem state when expanded

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I need to know how to change background  of expanded list item when it is actually expanded. We have ListItem which is expanded and opens another items, but we still see this parent item. I need to change its color.

Comment: Why was this question downvoted? Donwvotings should always come with a comment explaining the reason, otherwise, we'll never learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use listeners to change them.

```
listView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) { 
        // code to set your background to your expanded color
    } 
}); 

listView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) { 
        // code to set your background back to your collapsed color
    } 
});
```

Comment: Could you tell me how can I fetch this particular view to operate with it in this methods? How sould I use groupPosition?

Answer (score 2):

I am a little late but we can change ce layout of a group view with the `BaseExpandableListAdapter` method

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

Actually, this method  is called when the group state changes (expanded/collapsed). With the boolean `isExpanded` you can call a refresh UI method of your group view.

Hope it helps.